# while deploying to tomcat I'm getting issue : Calling stop() on failed component

Tags: tomcat, logging, deployment

19-Nov-2018 16:34:36.863 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy Calling stop() on failed component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] to trigger clean-up did not complete.
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.hasLoggingConfig()Z
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:457)

19-Nov-2018 16:34:36.864 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to destroy component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

19-Nov-2018 16:34:36.864 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy Calling stop() on failed component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]] to trigger clean-up did not complete.
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: same code deployed on front end server its working fine ,but if i'm trying on local server its not deploying

Comment: Are both systems different in Tomcat versions, Java versions, different jars in tomcat/lib ?